# My listview is not getting refreshed. What to do?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using an `ArrayAdapter` with an `ListView` to have a list on string type with `android.R.simple_list_view1;`

But it is not updating.

```
package com.pratham.cricket1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView t1,t2;
    String over_format;

    public int ta,tb;
    public String inning;
    public int w1,w2,extras;
    public int balls,w,t,ballsc,target,innings;
    LinearLayout l1,l2,l11,l22,outercover1,outercover2,big;
    ListView hj;
    ArrayList<String> a;
    ArrayAdapter<String> m;

    View v1;
    TextView g1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        big=(LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null,false);
        setContentView(big);
        over_format="";
        l1= (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.teamabatting,null,false);
        l2=(LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.teambbatting,null,false);

        outercover1=(LinearLayout)big.findViewById(R.id.outer_cover1);
        outercover2=(LinearLayout)big.findViewById(R.id.outer_cover2);
         a=new ArrayList<String>();

         m=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a);
        v1=(LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bowling,null,false);
        hj=v1.findViewById(R.id.overs);
        hj.setAdapter(m);

        innings=1;

        Intent i2=getIntent();
        Bundle b2=i2.getExtras();
        if(!b2.isEmpty()){
            balls=b2.getInt("Balls");
            t=b2.getInt("Team won toss");
            w=b2.getInt("Winning team chose");

        }else{}
        extras=0;

         ta=0;

         ta=0;



         w1=0;
         w2=0;

        t1=l1.findViewById(R.id.TeamA);

        t2=l2.findViewById(R.id.TeamB);
         l11=l1;
         l22=l2;





         ballsc=balls;
         TeamABatting();





    }
    public void a1(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(1,t1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(1,balls);


    }
    public void a2(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(2,t1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(2,balls);


    }
    public void a3(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(3,t1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(3,balls);


    }
    public void a4(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(4,t1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(4,balls);


    }
    public void a6(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(6,t1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(6,balls);


    }
    public void b1(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(1,t2);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(1,balls);


    }
    public void b2(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(2,t2);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(2,balls);


    }
    public void b3(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(3,t2);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(3,balls);



    }
    public void b4(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(4,t2);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(4,balls);


    }
    public void b6(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(6,t2);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(6,balls);


    }
    public  void score_add(int a ,TextView t3){
        if(t3==findViewById(R.id.TeamA)){
            ta+=a;
           Score_doner(t3,ta,w1,balls);
        }
        if(t3==findViewById(R.id.TeamB)){
            tb+=a;
            Score_doner(t3,tb,w2,balls);
        }


    }
    public void TeamAOut(View view){
        balls--;
        w1++;
        Score_doner(t1,ta,w1,balls);
        checkInningEnd(w1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(7,balls);
    }
    public void TeamBOut(View view){
        balls--;
        w2++;
        Score_doner(t2,tb,w2,balls);
        checkInningEnd(w2);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(7,balls);
    }
    public void Score_doner(TextView t4,int runs,int wicket,int b){
        t4.setText(Integer.toString(runs)+"/"+Integer.toString(wicket));
        g1.setText(Integer.toString(b));



    }
    public void TeamABatting(){


        outercover1.removeAllViews();
        outercover1.addView(l11);
       outercover2.removeAllViews();
        View v1=(LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bowling,null,false);
        outercover2.addView(v1);
        if(innings==2){
            TextView t8=v1.findViewById(R.id.target);
            t8.setText(Integer.toString(ta));
        }else{
            inning="1b";
        }
        g1=v1.findViewById(R.id.ballsleft);
        g1.setText(Integer.toString(balls));







    }
    public void TeamBBatting(){
        outercover2.removeAllViews();
        outercover2.addView(l22);
        outercover1.removeView(l1);
        View v1=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bowling,null);
        outercover1.addView(v1);
        if(innings==2){
            TextView t8=v1.findViewById(R.id.target);
            t8.setText(Integer.toString(ta));
        }else{
            inning="1a";
        }
        g1=v1.findViewById(R.id.ballsleft);
        balls=ballsc;
        g1.setText(Integer.toString(balls));

    }
    public void AExtras(View view){
        extras++;
        score_add(1,t1);

    }
    public void BExtras(View view){
        score_add(1,t2);

    }
    public  void Adots(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(0,t1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(0,balls);

    }
    public  void Bdots(View view){
        balls--;
        score_add(0,t1);
        checkInningsEnd(balls);
        make_over_format(0,balls);

    }
    public void checkInningEnd(int a){
        if(innings!=2) {
            if (a == 10 && w1 == 10) {
                balls=ballsc;
                innings = 2;
                inning="2a";
                TeamBBatting();
            } else if (a == 10 && w2 == 10) {
                balls=ballsc;
                innings = 2;
                inning="2b";
                TeamABatting();
            }
        }else if(a==10&&w1==10&&w2==10){
            Intent i1=new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i1);


        }

        }
        public void checkInningsEnd(int b){
        if(b==0&&inning=="1a"){
            balls=ballsc;
            innings = 2;
            inning="2b";
            TeamABatting();

        }else if(b==0&&inning=="1b"){
            balls=ballsc;
            innings = 2;
            inning="2a";
            TeamBBatting();

        }else if(b==0&&(inning=="2a"|| inning=="2b")){
            Intent i1=new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i1);

        }

        }
        public void make_over_format(int ak,int vb){
            Log.e("Is it comming", "make_over_format: " );
        if(vb%6!=0){
            over_format+="    "+Integer.toString(ak);


        }else{
            a.add(over_format);

            Log.e("The value of over:", "make_over_format: "+m.getItem(0) );
            m.notifyDataSetChanged();

            over_format="";




        }


        }
    }
```

What should i do?
Whats wrong in my code?
Is it because I am inflating the `view` from an `layout` file?

The `activity` is called on from another `activity`.
It is not giving any error. I do not understand.

The `listview` is not updating and it is totally blank

Comment: I think you should call `m.add(over_format);` instead of `a.add(over_format);`

Comment: Not working in my case.

Comment: What do you see in the log? Is the `make_over_format` function called? Also the `else` part?

Comment: All the logs are printing properly except that the value of over_format. is staying the same. Yes also the else part ;

Comment: The log is:E/Is it comming: make_over_format: 
E/Is it comming: make_over_format: 
E/Is it comming: make_over_format: 
E/Is it comming: make_over_format: 
E/Is it comming: make_over_format: 
E/Is it comming: make_over_format: 
E/The value of over:: make_over_format:     1    1    1    1    1